# Case Insensitive list OptionParser

Tags: ruby

I am trying to use Ruby's OptionParser to parse command line args. One of my parameters is a predefined list of acceptable strings which I am defining like this

```
opts.on('-p', '--project-name PROJECT', PROJECTS, 'The Project name', "{#{PROJECTS.join ', '}}"){|p| options.project = p}
```

where `PROJECTS` is a predefined list of strings (I'm on Ruby 1.8.7). How do I tell OptionsParser that the POJECTS list should be used to match the argument in a case insensitive way? I saw the class OptionParser::List might have something for that, I'm just not sure how to use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass a `Regexp` instead of the `PROJECTS` array. The `i` modifier at the end makes it case insensitive:

```
/#{Regexp.union(PROJECTS).source}/i
#=> /foo|bar|baz/i
```

Here's a full working example:

```
require 'optparse'

options = Struct.new(:project).new

PROJECTS = %w{foo bar baz}
ALLOWED_PROJECTS = /#{Regexp.union(PROJECTS).source}/i

OptionParser.new do |opts|
  opts.on('-p', '--project-name PROJECT', ALLOWED_PROJECTS, 'The Project name', "{#{PROJECTS.join ', '}}") do |p|
    options.project = p
  end
end.parse!

p options
```

Usage:

```
$ ruby foo.rb -p foo
#<struct project="foo">

$ ruby foo.rb -p FOO
#<struct project="FOO">

$ ruby foo.rb -p bar
#<struct project="bar">

$ ruby foo.rb -p bAz
#<struct project="baz">

$ ruby foo.rb -p quux
foo.rb:16:in `<main>': invalid argument: -p quux (OptionParser::InvalidArgument)
```

Comment: Don't you mean `Regexp.union(PROJECTS)` instead of that map/escape/stringify/join/regexify stuff?

Comment: @muistooshort I tried `Regexp.union` before, but then how do you make the resulting regex case insensitive? If you do `/#{Regexp.union PROJECTS}/i` you get `/(?-mix:foo|bar|baz)/i` which matches case-sensitively, because the mixed in regex has its own modifiers. The only alternative I can think of is `Regexp.union PROJECTS.map{|p| /#{p}/i}` which is not better and produces a more complicated regex like `/(?i-mx:foo)|(?i-mx:bar)|(?i-mx:baz)/`.

Comment: @muistooshort ok another alternative would be `Regexp.new(Regexp.union(PROJECTS).source, Regexp::IGNORECASE)`, that's the best alternative so far I think. Changed my answer.

Comment: Right, the case insensitivity part complicates things. Too bad `Regexp.union` doesn't take any flags.

Comment: Ok I found yet another alternative: `/#{Regexp.union(PROJECTS).source}/i`, I really like this one, does not feel as clunky as the other approaches.

Comment: I would prefer a native alternative (as I said, the list class might be able to handle it). I'll wait a day or 2 then mark this as accepted if no alternative is posted.

Comment: Nice, `/#{Regexp.union(PROJECTS).source}/i` is cleaner than the alternatives.